# Complicated Django annotation with self reference

Tags: python, database, django, self-reference

Given the two models:

- `Floor` that has a reference to itself called `previousFloor` which can be `null` for the first `Floor`
- `Room` which of course can only be in one `Floor` (but there are multiple rooms in a `Floor`)

**I need a query that returns all rooms on the top floor.**

---

In order to achieve that, I created a function in the `Floor` model called `get_next_floor` which would return the `Floor` with `previousFloor` set to `self` and return `None` if the filter was empty (this is the last `Floor`). So another function in the `Floor` model called `is_last_floor`, would return `True` if `get_next_floor` returned `None`, and otherwise would returned `False`.

In the end I would loop through all the rooms and have to call `is_last_floor` for the `Floor` the `Room` is in, in order to decide if it fits my condition.

This problem can be slightly optimized by saving the already found last `Floor` during the loop.

Since this is only an abstraction of my real problem and I am working on a large database, this solution is no longer a viable option because of the bad performance of the loop.

**Is there a way to implement this in one query with annotation?**

Comment: In the end I would loop through all the rooms and have to call is_last_floor for every Floor the Room is in, in order to decide if it fits my condition. ... I believe this is a mistake, as you stated that each room is in only one floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A floor which is the top `Floor` is surely one which has no other `Floor` referring to it as `previousFloor`.

So:

```
top_floors = Floor.objects.exclude(id__in=Floor.objects.filter(previous_floor__isnull=False).values_list('previous_floor', flat=True))
```

which translates to:

```
SELECT "core_floor"."id", "core_floor"."name", "core_floor"."previous_floor_id" FROM "core_floor" WHERE NOT ("core_floor"."id" IN (SELECT U0."previous_floor_id" FROM "core_floor" U0 WHERE U0."previous_floor_id" IS NOT NULL))
```

HOWEVER MySQL is not great at nested queries so it may be more efficient to do:

```
lower_floors = Floor.objects.filter(previous_floor__isnull=False).values_list('previous_floor', flat=True)
top_floors = Floor.objects.exclude(id__in=list(covered_floors))
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

Then to get rooms on top floors:

```
Room.objects.filter(floor__in=top_floors)
```

Comment: I was too quick to accept your answer... the problem is that in my case the first floor is the one that has no previousFloor

Comment: In that case you can surely just use `Floor.objects.filter(previous_floor__isnull=True)`?

Comment: but that would only return the first level floors not the top level floors

Comment: My original answer does get you the top level floors.  It will get you all the floors that don't have any other floors above them (i.e. there are no other floors which refer to them as previous floor)